# Other way to ask Request for Permission for authorize application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

I want to know how to add this functionality (I don't know how it calls), when a user clicks on application in Facebook, this window is shown:

[image: Example of an application that requests access to profile]

How to change traditional "Request for Permission" windows to this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application settings in Facebook you can configure the new authorization dialog:

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/auth

Just follow screen instructions, you can add a description, headline, extended permissions, etc. (If you add extended permissions, a second permissions screen will be shown to the user, so the user would have to go through 2 screens before actually entering your app).